# Partially Blurry Text in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

After formatting my Windows 7 I found out that the text on my screen is partially blurry.For example as am reading a text the far left corner is blurry then in the middle is OK and then at the far right corner it goes  blury again.

I am using a Toshiba laptop,graphics card. Intel core i3. Before the format I didn't have this problem.I tried the Enable ClearType Text  but it didn't work.My resolution is 1366x768 and it's fine.
BTW the text is blurry in everything I watch on my screnn.(Desktop,Control Panel,Google,Youtube,Wiki).My eyes are 100% fine and I had 15 difirent guys pointing  out what is wrong with my screen and the all said the same thing as me.

EDIT:I formatted my PC and didnt use the factroy built-in windows this time(but i used Windows 7 as before).Does this have anything to do with it???

Comment: Have you confirmed the correct/latest Toshiba driver for the video card? Any errors in Device Manager? Intel chipset updated to latest?

Comment: Yes i tried to update as a guy suggested and it says its already updated...

Comment: So...Where do i look up this stuff

Comment: Chek the EDIT in my post

Comment: What is the monitor? because this sounds like something that is more likely to occur on a CRT monitor?  Are you using VGA connection? that gets "converted" sort of in any digital monitor like a LCD , and the monitor itself could have interpolation settings, or pix=pix or fill, or other settings to adjust how the analog is sent to the screen?

Comment: I gave my laptop to ''programer'' to formatt it and he messed everything up...Now i try to launch games at steam that runed perfectly fine before the formatt and i get this message:  '' No suitable graphics card found.Could not find a Direct3D device that supports the XNA Framework Reach profile.Verify that a suitable graphics device is installed.Make sure the desktop is not locked,and that no other application is running in full screen mode.Avoid running under Remote Desktop or as a Windows service.Check the full display properties to make sure hardware accelaration is full

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Adjust ClearType text

Comment: Tried it and doesent work...

Comment: Toshiba laptop,graphics card<=== That is not showing in device manager. If you have an actual graphics card, you need to download it from Toshiba:  http://support.toshiba.com/drivers

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the graphic card driver, and let the driver choose the best resolution for your laptop (Recomended)

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how to update the driver???

Comment: If you have a genuine windows 7 just take the last updates, or more spefic `My Computer-> Properties -> Device Manager -> Display Adapter` do an driver update

Comment: It tells me that is already updated...

Comment: Somehow the windows update is a little lazy sometimes and give that short answer. You can try take the model number of card drive {nvidia, intel, ATI etc} and find the driver online directly from the manufacturer

Comment: So.I just search intel core i3 driver update...Please can you give me some more detailed instructions.I am not that good with this kinda stuff XD

Comment: The i3 is the cpu. You want the display adapter

Comment: It says standard graphics adapter VGA.

Comment: BTW Check the EDIT in my post.

Comment: intel core i3 is you CPU, anyway toshiba lead to a easy automatic way: http://www.toshiba.eu/innovation/generic/SUPPORT_PORTAL/

Answer (score 0):

Please add the exact model of the Toshiba.

You seem to have the generic Windows VGA driver and you need the specific one for your Model.  This could be a driver for video only or itcould be part of the Intel Chipset package. The [Toshiba Driver and Software site](http://support.toshiba.com/drivers) will allow you to enter your model number and then download and install the various packages specific to your model and operating system(Windows 7 x32 or x64).  There are several specific Toshiba utilities that you may also be missing.

Installing all packages from the Toshiba site will assure you have proper latest drivers.

Avoid Windows Update for updating things like Video as the generic Windows drivers for various video chipset vendors often do not work.  In many cases the manufacturer may have made system specific changes for the video system. Using the Toshiba drivers in this case should resolve your issue.